# Cannot Load Civi - Unknown column in civicrm_cache Select

Tags: database, core

After making configuration changes to the Parameter Group for both the database and cluster of my Amazon Aurora database I can no longer access CiviCRM. I get the following error:
Error code 19, "DB Error: no such field". It has this for debug info:

`SELECT path, data, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expired_date) AS expires FROM civicrm_cache WHERE group_name = "2c60b3a2e8a19ac496e9716cc54d45a8" [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column '2c60b3a2e8a19ac496e9716cc54d45a8' in 'where clause']`

Before I made the changes to my server the entire Drupal site was only loading the install page with issues with the cache.  I believe this was because the max_allowed_packets was not large enough. I have now set the max_allowed_packets to the highest size using *Parameter Groups.*

Drupal cannot bootstrap and *cv flush* will not work either because it appears to be attempting to bootstrap Drupal. I have truncated the civicrm_cache table.  Before I did that there was a group_name value of *2c60b3a2e8a19ac496e9716cc54d45a8* in the table.

I have Drupal 9.3.3. We have been running 9.3.3 for about a week before we have had problems. We have CiviCRM 5.45.2. We have been running this for about a week as well.

I am not sure what to do to get CiviCRM to correct this query so that I can bootstrap everything.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you made your config changes did you turn on ANSI or ANSI_QUOTES in your sql_mode?

It prevents using `"` as a string quoting character which is not a standard string quoting character in sql, and so will break civi since civi does nonstandard things.

Comment: Thank you but that is not how the database is configured now.  I did turn on ANSI but then I turned it off. Could I have damaged the database? I think I will restore from a clone just to see if that works.

Comment: I don't think it would have damaged it, but it's possible mysql needs a restart to pick up the change. If you do `SELECT @@sql_mode;` you can confirm if ANSI is removed or not.

Comment: I should not have needed to but I needed to restart the database. Thanks!